# Display Shopping Cart items in phtml Contactform (Magento)

Tags: magento, php

Hello i just signed in to ask this question. i try to fix that issue with the given answers in that forum, but somthing won´t work. 
I just want to include the items in the shopping cart to an text-field in an **`magento kontactform`**. i use form.phtml

i try to display the sidebar cart with:

```
  <label for="comment">Artikel</label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="Artikel" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3">

                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
```

but i get this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getProduct() on a
>   non-object in
>   **/www/htdocs/xxxxx/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml**
>   on line **29**

in line 29 is:

```
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
```

so may someone can help me, and sorry for my cruel english :-)

Comment: Use this code <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

Comment: Also you need to comment if condition "<?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>"

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, but it still dosen´t work, i´m a php newbe so maybe i did something basicly wrong. I ad the code
`code` <?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
           <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/‌​cart/sidebar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                        
                     <?php endif; ?>
 `code`

Comment: but i always get an blank box. i try it with and without "
may the tag <textarea> is a Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You are using **core/template** block that's why you are getting error so please use **checkout/cart_sidebar** block. Please replace your code with below code.

Your Code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Replace with**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Thanks